# yii2 css file won't load because it's MIME type text/html is not text/css on windows7 apache server

Tags: css, apache, yii2

I'm starting on Yii2, and i want to change the theme. So far I've downloaded theme from http://yii2.themefactory.net and followed this steps

```
'view' => [
  'theme' => [
       'pathMap' => ['@app/views' => '@app/themes/mytheme'],
       'baseUrl' => '@web/themes/mytheme',
    ],
  ],
```

on config/web.php file. Now when I try to load the site I got this

**css file won't load because it's MIME type text/html is not text/css**

Answer (score 0):

configure your apache server. Your mime types are probably wrong.

You'll need `mod_mime` apache module enabled, and ensure you have these lines in your httpd.conf (or .htaccess)

```
AddType text/css .css
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have this line 'LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so' uncommented on httpd.conf, and i have added .htacces file to my project root, but I still got the error. Can u help me pls

Comment: @ocr, my personal advice - do not use apache on windows.. cause it's always a pain! ;) I can only ask a bunch of questions to check: Are you sure that mod_mime is loaded ? (create a file with <?php phpinfo() ?> and  check if mod_mime is listed on the generated page). Are you sure that .htaccess file is parsed by server? (AllowOverride All in server configuration or your domain folder configuration (non in .htaccess)) re you 100% sure tht css file has .css extension and actially exists when loaded (check in browser console that it's actually contains css and not apache 404 page).

Comment: again thanks for your time. I'm using XAMPP (apache included), so I kinda have no choice. About your questions

Comment: About your questions #1 I've done phpinfo() inside a file.php and yes mod_mime module is loaded. #2 My httpd.conf file has AllowOverride ALL option enabled. #3 I'm sure the css file has correct css extension.#4 Yes i can see the file on the Style Editor in my Developer Console. I was googling and perhaps the file is SASS or LESS precompiled and my web server can't "understand" the file